# Java Web/JSF/Persistence: Simple authentication with user roles

Tags: java, jsf, persistence

I'm working on the following seemingly basic task:

''Create a dvd store. The system has two types of users: admins and basic users. Admins can perform CRUD on DVD items, basic users can purchase dvds.''

I'm using NetBeans + GlassFish and did the following:

- prepared the database schema with tables: users, dvds, transactions
- created entity beans for the three tables (New > Entity classes from database...)
- created JSF CRUD pages for the entity beans (New > JSF Pages from entity classes...)

How exactly do I integrate user authentication here?

I've tried the following, but failed somewhere in the process: apply an AuthenticationPhaseListener that attempts to intercept all requests and route them based on whether there's an user on the session and their role.

Is there something simple i'm missing here? Can you please outline for me the different classes (and their type / annotations needed / whether they need to be managed beans etc) and pages that I need for this.

Basically, I just want this to be over as soon as possible, as it's driving me borderline insane. There's just so much new technology for me involved here it's overwhelming. Any pointer to the right direction is highly appreciated.

Thanks a ton,

-- Dan

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring here? If so, you really might want to take a look at Spring Security. I know I'm throwing another possible new technology at you here, but application security should be handled by tools like Spring Security, and not writing a homegrown version yourself. What you want is role-based access, and Spring Security certainly can do that for you.

With Spring Security, you can set up that if the link has "/store/admin/*" pattern, then only admins can access it. Anything else will be open to basic users. When someone hits that link, Spring Security will automatically check if that person has enough privilege, if not it will automatically redirect the user to a login page before proceeding. Once you have properly configured it, you really don't need to even think about handling the security yourself.

For more info, visit this link: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Comment: Thanks, I'm not currently using Spring but I will take a look.